# T0 find the value of $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^{2}+kn}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, riemann-sum

> What is $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^{2}+kn}}$$.I try to check whether series can be written as telescoping series but it doesn't work. I am getting no idea how to start?

Answer (score 3):

Write it as $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+k/n}} $$
and interpret this as a Riemann sum for an integral.

Answer (score 2):

By Riemann sum we have $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^{2}+kn}}=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+k/n}}\to \int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x}}= 2(\sqrt2-1)$$

Comment: Actually I don't know this Riemann sum formula..I searched on net but it doesn't show related results.

Comment: Can you suggest any link?

Comment: @omkarGirkar see here https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjN4dGm9a_YAhUO_KQKHWIOAkMQFggvMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FRiemann_sum&usg=AOvVaw3Pkb1FCutGVvTHPEoPOIte